# Why is numpy array indexing slower than built-in Python list?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have done the following experiment:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: l = range(5000000)

In [3]: a32 = np.array(l, dtype='uint32')

In [4]: a64 = np.array(l, dtype='uint64')

In [5]: %timeit l[101233]
The slowest run took 39.00 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 30.6 ns per loop

In [6]: %timeit a32[101233]
The slowest run took 281.55 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 88.9 ns per loop

In [7]: %timeit a64[101233]
The slowest run took 22192.85 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 85.9 ns per loop
```

I'm expecting indexing element in numpy array should be about the same speed as in a Python list.
But it turns out to be more than two times slower, and the performance and be very unstable (see the result of `a64[101233]`, the slowest run took 22192.85 times longer ...).

What could be the reason of this behavior?

Comment: see [Numpy individual element access slower than for lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281680/numpy-individual-element-access-slower-than-for-lists)