# Time processing array vs list

Tags: python

Why when I use a list in this code is faster than an array?

```
import numpy as np

x = 10000
y = 10000
array = np.ones((x,y))

s = 0
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        s = s + array[i][j]

print(s)
```

*56,79 seconds elapsed , 396.818.753.403 instructions (perf stat)*

```
x = 10000
y = 10000
array = [[1.0,] * y for x in range(x)]

s = 0
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        s = s + array[i][j]

print(s)
```

*19,12 seconds time elapsed, 168.298.886.097 instructions (perf stat)*

Comment: Are you benchmarking only the `for` loops, or the whole script?

Comment: I'm benchmarking in all the script

Comment: I think the rest is negligible, the difference is too big

Comment: Probably yes, but I want to reproduce the same that you're running.

Comment: It seems someone else has also asked this same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281680/numpy-individual-element-access-slower-than-for-lists), and got a nice answer. I'll mark this as a duplicate.