# Could I compare part of liste?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

This code will select the 6 or more than positive values of the list 'a'

```
a=np.array([1.01, -1.58, 0.64, 1.38, 0.69, 0.91, 1.34, 1.03, 1.39, 0.94, -1.01,0.16])
b= np.zeros(13)
for i in range(6):
    if (a[i] > 0 and a[i+1] > 0 and a[i+2] > 0 and a[i+3] > 0\
        and a[i+4] > 0 and a[i+5] > 0 and a[i+6] > 0) :
            
            b[i] = a[i]
            b[i+1] = a[i+1]
            b[i+2] = a[i+2]
            b[i+3] = a[i+3]
            b[i+4] = a[i+4]
            b[i+5] = a[i+5]
            b[i+6] = a[i+6]
```

I would like to make it shorter, I tried :

```
for i in range (6):
    if (a[i:i+6]) > 0:
        b[i:i+6] = a[i:i+6]
```

Comment: @Steve sorry for overwriting the edit, I thought that `#` signs are comments and there were some more typos to fix

Comment: what should ur code do

Comment: it should take 6 or more than + valeus from the array 'a' and stock its in 'b' as in the first part

Comment: @YoussefGC - no problem on the edit thing

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed so quickly.  I have some questions for the OP, but I understand what they are basically trying to do.  I think the SO community has generally gotten way too trigger happy regarding the closing of questions.

Comment: Agreed. At least the current version of the question is quite read-able. Has OP's code/effort. Need info on expected output and what _"6 or more than positive values of the list 'a'"_ means. Do you mean 6 or more consecutive positive numbers? (Voting to reopen.) Also, add your expected output for how `b` should look.

Comment: Exactelly  @Aneroid

Comment: `if all((a[i:i+6]) > 0):` should get around the unstated `ValueError`

Comment: @YoussefGC - this may not be exactly what you need, but maybe a starting point; `for i in range(len(a) - 5):
    if all([x > 0 for x in a[i:i+6]]):
        r = a[i:i + 6]
` - this sets `r` to each of the sublists that meet your criteria.  I wasn't sure what you wanted to do with the result, so I leave that to you.

Comment: @hpaulj - that isn't valid Python code, is it?  You're comparing a list to an integer.  I don't think that will work?

Comment: Thank you @Steve and hpaulj
that's exactly what I need !

Comment: @Steve How could I do ?
sorry this is my first time here

Comment: @YoussefGC - I don't see a lot more you could have done.  I think your question was fine.

Comment: @Steve Exactly
Thank you !

Comment: @Steve, if `a` is a numpy array, then what I wrote is correct.

Comment: @hpaulj - yes.  Apologies - I forgot that numpy was behind that.  No worries.

Answer (score 0):

In the shortened version, the main thing you need to change is `if (a[i:i+6]) > 0:`. Also, the length of `a` is 12 and `b` is 13. Edit 1: (as per [@Steve's comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65025119/could-i-compare-part-of-liste/65025605#comment114960109_65025605)) Additionally, the index `range` loop could also be generalised from `for i in range(6)` to `for i in range(len(a)-5)`So:

```
b = np.zeros(len(a))
# b is 
# array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
for i in range(len(a)-5):
    if all(a[i:i+6] > 0):
        b[i:i+6] = a[i:i+6]

b
# output:
# array([0.  , 0.  , 0.64, 1.38, 0.69, 0.91, 1.34, 1.03, 1.39, 0.94, 0.  , 0.  ])
```

Edit 2, as per [@hpaulj's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65025119/could-i-compare-part-of-liste/65025605?noredirect=1#comment114961222_65025605), since `a` is a numpy array, we don't need to iterate over the slice, since numpy will apply the `>` operator to each element of the array (slice) and return an array of `[`True`,` False`, ...]`. It looks like this for the first loop:

Eg `a[0:0+6] > 0` returns `array([ True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True])`.

---

One notable downside of checking exactly 6 elements at a time is that if the is a longer group of consecutive positive numbers, it will be filled in in the next loops, and over-writing the same value already in `b`. So not very optimized. Might be better to have an explicit check of indexes until you get a non-positive (or the end) and making sure you're count is currently > 6.

Comment: Nice answer.  I think `for i in range(6):` should be generalized based on the length of the input list. =  `for i in range(len(a)-5):`

Comment: Good catch. Since I generalised the length of `b` anyway. Editing.

Comment: I'd also strongly ask/suggest that you not post REPL code runs.  They prevent others from being able quickly copy/paste your code to try it or make use of it. - they are also generally less readable

Comment: Many of us post `ipython` REPL code.  That can be copy-n-pasted back into a an `ipython` session (at least the `IN` parts).  The original for-loop portion of this answer also works in an `ipython` session.  But I often do post headerless versions of functions.

Comment: If `a` is an array, you don't need to iterate in the test.

Comment: @hpaulj Have added that to the answer and an explanation.

Comment: If I'm posting just a short snippet/correction to the OP's code, then I do it as REPL, since I can also show intermediate outputs without adding print's. But I can see how that can make copy-pasting difficult, especially for newer folks.

Comment: @hpaulj - what many people do is not all that relevant, nor is ipython, since we don't all use that.  I was just giving you a suggestion as to how to make your answers as simple as possible for everyone to evaluate and use. I don't use ipython, and I'm often grumbling under my breath converting a REPL thing to real python code so that I can check an answer or help someone with their problem.  I doubt I'm the only one who has this reaction to REPL code, and I can't see anyone having an issue the other way.  So it's just a matter of catering to the widest audience possible. - just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting this one - thought I'd add this alternative approach which includes the optimization I mentioned in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65025605/1431750):

This version is much longer and requires hand-coding the tracking of indexes for each series of positive numbers. But it has major performance advantages, mentioned below.

```py
a = np.array([1.01, -1.58, 0.64, 1.38, 0.69, 0.91, 1.34, 1.03, 1.39, 0.94, -1.01, 0.16,])
b = np.zeros(len(a))

MIN_CONSECUTIVE = 6  # number of consecutive numbers wanted
first, last, c = -1, -1, 0  # index of first & last positive number, count of +ve nums
nums = []  # hold each series of consecutive positive numbers

for i, n in enumerate(a):
    if n > 0:
        nums.append(n)
        first = i if first == -1 else first
        last = i
        c += 1
    else:
        if c >= MIN_CONSECUTIVE:
            b[first:last+1] = nums
        first, last, c = -1, -1, 0  # reset
        nums = []  # reset
        if i > len(a) - MIN_CONSECUTIVE - 1:  # shortcut exit if there aren't
            break                             # enough elems left for consecutive

else:  # if the loop completes without `break`
    if c >= MIN_CONSECUTIVE:  # also check after the loop completes
        b[first:last+1] = nums

b  # -> array([0.  , 0.  , 0.64, 1.38, 0.69, 0.91, 1.34, 1.03, 1.39, 0.94, 0.  , 0.  ])
```

Why this is better:

1. This one visits and accesses each item in the numpy array (or python list) ***exactly once***.

   - the method you were trying, and provided in the comments and in my previous answer, looks up *overlapping* series of elements in the array multiple times
   - previous one also re-writes to `b` multiple times and over-writes with the same value
2. This only writes to `b` once each series is found and completed.
3. I am tracking indexes with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) but I'm **not using indexes to access elements**. Index access on python lists is slower than just iterating through the list's elements. [The same is true for numpy arrays.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311751/1431750)
4. For your given list, this one runs in less then half the time of the previous answer:

   - this: 14.6 µs ± 584 ns
   - prev: 31.9 µs ± 1.13 µs